# How to translate “Tanzverbot” to English?

Tags: german-to-english, meaning

How would you translate the German word *Tanzverbot?* More interestingly,
why can’t I find any (“official”) translation online, nor a Wikipedia article about the issue, even though (probably) Germany is not the only country that had and has this issue?

[German Wikipedia article: Tanzverbot](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanzverbot)

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You linked to a Wikipedia article while you're saying you couldn't find it. Are you looking for the meaning of the word or its etymology or its reasons or what?

Comment: @Gigili: OP seems to be looking for a translation (probably into English). There does not appear to be an *English Wikipedia article*.

Comment: @bitmask I think, you don't find an article on WP, because there isn't any word in English that expresses such a thing. .... At grundwald2.0: But this could be a good question on ELU ;p

Comment: If grunwald2.0 knows the meaning, this question is not for German L&U, but for Englisch. English expertise is asked here.

Comment: @userunknown I agree. I am waiting for a statement to clarify the question's intention.

Comment: Translation requests from German to English are **on topic** here (we do have [other similar questions](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation-de-to-en) that were not closed). This even more so when a requested word **does not exist in English** and thus can not be easily looked up in a dictionary. Why should people from ELU know better what a German *Tanzverbot* is?

Comment: @Takkat: grunwald2.0 knows what a Tanzverbot is. He doesn't know what the english word for it is, which might require an expert for the English language. You can learn better and better German but will not learn the English term that way. It's not about nuances of the German language.

Comment: @Takkat Of course, ELU's do not know better what a German *Tanzverbot* is, but you can explain the meaning of *Tanzverbot* with your own words and/or you can go on with my proposals and asking *which one is better in case of religion, traditional, whatever context or is there any better word*. Then ELU's are able to give a better solution then most here on GLU.

Comment: @Takkat Regarding on or off topic. I looked up on meta and found a question discussing this fact. The (most voted answer)(http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/a/152/1224) makes this question something between on and off topic. I wrote in a comment I am waiting for a clarification, but he already logged in after my answer and Gigili's comment and he doesn't pointed out anything. So I voted to close, since I am in belief that is just was a translation question based on general reference.

Comment: Sorry for answering so late! I didn't really login before @Em1. I don't know where you got that from? I'm using a lot of other SE sites in the network though! Yes I am looking for a translation. And yeah, probably it would have been a better fit on the ELU site! Never asked for a translation before, so I didn't know if I want to translate TO another language I had to ask there. I thought here more people know, because it is important to get the meaning of this word, because it is so specific! Or as said before, it doesn't exist in English probably. So that is why I asked here...

Comment: @grunwald2.0 Your question is on the brink of off-topic. If it belongs to here is not 100% clear or better: It is not decided unanimously. It depends on how the askers background knowledge is based. Because it seems very much, that you are fully aware of the meaning of *Tanzverbot*, I think it is off-topic. The translations proposal what I did is very well possible for you, isn't it?

Comment: I'm unsure what this has specifically to do with me. As outlined, I checked the dictionary before and saw the word isn't defined. I could've just asked on proz. And yes I know that "Verbot" means "ban". **But** my question was: "Why can't I find a wikipedia article (or: historic context worldwide, in English) about the issue, even though GER is not the only country that had and has this issue?" I know this question might be extremly offtopic. Still both questions originate out of: Why is "Tanzverbot" **ignored** linguistically and historically in English? Guess I should head over to ELU...

Comment: Keep cool, grunwald, translation requests are on-topic here. The question can stay here as it is. It also has a nice answer.

Comment: The fact why you don't find an english translation is just, that you can produce compositas like that in German, but not in English. You have to use multiple words in English.

Comment: "No dancing! " would be the simplest translation.

Comment: Was ist Alkoholverbot, Fahrverbot, Arbeitsverbot, ...? @rogermue: "Kein Tanzen!" ist sicher kein Äquivalent zu Tanzverbot. Simple, but wrong.

Comment: This question is not precise enough. Words do not only have a meaning, they have also a context where they are used. "Tanzverbot" in a bureaucratic text might be differently translated than "Tanzverbot" on a warning sign in a public place, or "Tanzverbot" in a private conversation. So, you should at least describe the context you intend this for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I guess right, you're looking for an English word.

I think there are two words that fit in this context.

1. **ban**:

   *Ban* is an official or legal prohibition <sup>[Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ban?q=ban)</sup>

   > Several people were arrested Saturday afternoon at the Jefferson Memorial, protesting the recent court decision that upheld a ban on dancing at the memorial. <sup>[Source](http://jasonfeldman.wordpress.com/2011/05/29/you-are-not-allowed-to-dance-in-america/)</sup>
   >
   > Dance clubs hope for £150 million windfall as Home Office moves to change 1790 Act that bans dancing on the Sabbath <sup>[Guardian](http://www.guardian.co.uk/uk/1999/jan/24/patrickwintour.theobserver?INTCMP=SRCH)</sup>
2. **prohibition**:

   *Prohibition* is the action of forbidding something, especially by law <sup>[Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prohibition?q=prohibition)</sup>

   You can also use *prohibition* in religious contexts.

   > In extreme evangelical colleges, like Baylor University in Texas, Wheaton College in Illinois and Cornerstone University in Michigan, it was even prohibited for students to dance in public <sup>[Guardian](http://www.guardian.co.uk/stage/theatreblog/2007/jan/31/dance1?INTCMP=SRCH)</sup>

I suggest: *ban on dance* or *prohibition on dance*

Comment: I always thought *prohibition* was strongly related to *alcohol ban*. Isn't it?

Comment: @bitmask If you follow the link to Oxford, there is this statement: *the prevention by law of the manufacture and sale of alcohol, especially in the US between 1920 and 1933*. So, you are right, but it is not only a prohibition on alcohol, if you take notice of the fact, that it is listed separately. And the Guardian link gives a good example for prohibition for religion reasons in context of dancing. I think, we can trust a source like that ;p

Comment: Thanks Em1 for this, but how would I include the dancing part? "dancing ban"? And awesome sourcing, I need to learn how to highlight and cite like you just did. :)

Comment: @grunwald2.0 Regarding sourcing: Click on edit and you will see it ;p (But then *cancel* ;p ) Regarding including: Don't know. Depends on context, phrasing, ...

Comment: The word *Prohibition* (capitalized) by itself refers to the alcohol ban, yes. But you can talk of *prohibitions* of other things. The word sounds somewhat formal, but it fits in the context of governmental regulations or religious rules.

Answer (score 8):

After this question has been asked, Wikipedia pages in other languages have been linked to the German page "Tanzverbot". According to those, the Dutch translation for example is "dansverbod" and the English "dancing ban".

Answer (score 3):

Prohibition of (public) dance is OK.
Usually declared on the so called "Stille Feiertage" as Good Friday or Totensonntag (Sunday in commemoration of the dead — in protestant regions in Germany).